# Drawing on Canvas, Adding Stickers, Custom Bitmaps - Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawable

I am looking to implement a feature that allows me to take predefined borders/images and place them over top a picture that a user has taken.

This app would be very similar to the functionality of Aviary, or Photo Editing Apps.

I cannot seem to figure out how to draw many images (say mustaches, noses, etc..) onto a canvas or view.

**Is there a specific method to accomplishing this stacked bitmap/filter editing?**  I tried creating a custom View, but I can only set 1 setContentView();

My code is relatively simple right now, but I just wanted to know if there was a method of stacking views, or bitmaps individually.

```
public class CustomView extends View {

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
}



@Override
public void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
    //Draw stuff in here
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.basketball);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);


}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomView m_View = new CustomView(this);
    setContentView(m_View);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic can be implemented many ways. It is based on your requirements and details of the application. Basically you can do something similar to this:

> ```
> @SuppressLint("WrongCall")
> @Override
> protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
>     // use for-int to avoid object (iterator) allocations
>     int count = mItems.size();
>     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
>         mItems.get(i).onDraw(canvas);
>     }
> }
> ```

```
ArrayList<Item> mItems;

static class Item {

    Context mContext;
    Drawable mDrawable;
    Rect mRect;
    int mResourceId;

    // resource ID to point to drawable resources
    public Item(Context context, int resourceId) {
        mContext = context;
        mResourceId = resourceId;
        mRect = new Rect();
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // allocate image only when it actually required
        if (mDrawable == null) {
            mDrawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mResourceId);
        }
        // manage mRect to place sticker and etc.
        if (mDrawable != null) {
            mDrawable.setBounds(mRect);
            mDrawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am in a situation where I need to be able to place individual "stickers" or "bitmaps" on top of a user selected photo/camera picture. Those individual images should be resizable/turnable.

Comment: Yes I understand. Your first item is your photo for example. Next item can be sticker or whatever where mRect is area (x,y,width,height) of the sticker.

Comment: I just have to get it implemented. I am looking to allow for resizing / moving the stickers so I am probably looking for something custom to manipulate the mRect graphically.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to create a CustomView class, and create many instances of that CustomView and add them dynamically?
Will the views overlap with eachother?

Comment: You can either use views or custom view or surfaceview to draw stickers. Really up to you. Yes, views overlap, the question is if you need then render it into some result bitmap. If so, you will need to write extra functionality to render to single bitmap all those overlapped views.

Comment: Where would the code you listed go? If I was to create a view I would like to be able to pass a resource ID as a parameter.

For example ---- I would press an image button >> It would create a  customview of the image like CustomView newView = new CustomView(resourceId) >> and than the view would appear on the screen with the ability to be manipulated.

Comment: That was just an idea and one of possible directions to go. What you are asking now is more to get code to copy/paste. That's not how it works around here.